# Check which ports are left open (vulnerable) and accessible in Windows OS from the Internet

Tags: windows, vulnerability-scanners, vulnerability

Since open ports are a security risk, I would like to know which ports are open to the Internet (outside my network). I wouldn't think of all open ports as security vulnerabilities just the ones exposed to the Internet. Is there a tool to check this?

Comment: I think you are looking for [nmap](https://nmap.org/)

Comment: You should specify within your question on which OS you would like to run such a tool, if you are interested in a software service provider. To avoid useless answer, and to be seen as a new born question, specify what you tested so far.

Comment: @danielAzuelos It is right there on the title ("Windows"). It is also there on the tags.

Comment: @BadSkillz nope. Nmap doesn't give an outside view of my network.

Comment: Do you mean "from Windows"? If yes, fix your title please.

Comment: Downvoters, My first question in this site. Please comment your reason, so that I can get it corrected.

Comment: @danielAzuelos: No, I meant "in windows". I have rearranged the prepositions in the title so that it is more clear now.

Comment: Pointing nmap to your external ip will scan it as if it was from an outside source. Else take a laptop and scan it from another location.

Comment: The "in Windows" isn't clear. When you perform a port scan you do it "from" a source (running a given OS appropriate to test vulnerabilities) "toward" a target (running a given other OS appropriate to have vulnerabilities). Within this context, `nmap` is far from a stupid answer.

Comment: @BadSkillz, that only works if you've got a NAT router, that router supports loopback routing, and it performs the loopback "outside" both NAT and firewall.  I've found very few devices that will do it.

Comment: Toddler, questions asking for tool recommendations are off topic for this site. See the help section for more information.

Comment: @NeilSmithline, this isn't a tool recommendation question, this is a "what sort of tool do I use to solve this problem" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [port scanner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner).  Specifically, you're looking for one hosted on a server somewhere to give you an outside look at your network.  There are a great many of them out there, of varying features and usefulness.

Comment: Thanks, care to name a few popular ones? My googlefu is failing as all I am getting is "nmap" which does not represent the outside look of my network.

Comment: I can't recommend any particular one, since I haven't used them in years.  I've got root-level access to computers on two different networks, so I can just use `nmap` from one to scan the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can check server's open ports with nmap command like this:
`sudo nmap -O remote_host`

For example running this for example.com domain:

```
sudo nmap -O example.com

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-04-10 14:39 EEST
Nmap scan report for example.com (93.184.216.34)
Host is up (0.068s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  open   https
1935/tcp closed rtmp
OS fingerprint not ideal because: Didn't receive UDP response. Please try again with -sSU
No OS matches for host

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.24 seconds
```

More examples with nmap: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-nmap-to-scan-for-open-ports-on-your-vps